# To check if user first time visit or not with COOKIES in Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee

I want to learn that is there a way to check if user first time visited the page or not in SERVLET. With cookies. I know doing it with Sessions. But I need to do it with only cookies. Is there any way? Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but that would not work on new computer and data would be lost if browser data is cleaned. Why do you need to check it using cookies anyways?
set cookie:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
```

chech if exists:

```
function checkCookie() {
var username = getCookie("username");
if (username != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + username);
} else {
    username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (username != "" && username != null) {
        setCookie("username", username, 365);
    }
}
}
```

php create cookie:

```
setcookie("name","value",time()+$int);
```

check if exists :

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]) {}
```

Comment: I could give an example, but I really need to know if what you are trying to do is based on logical reasoning or I should suggest to cahnge your approach

Comment: I know that it is not reliable

Comment: So then tell me why would you use this approach?

Comment: And I know checking it with Session tracking but I need to learn both approach to learn the scope deeply

Comment: just for testing purposes

Comment: will you help me?

Comment: But I neeed servlet java